# git commit is not working with "python was not found..." warning

Tags: python, git, git-bash, git-commit

I am trying to commit a couple of files using **git bash** on **windows 10**. After doing **git add**, the file get staged and appear in green. Next when I run **git commit** , there is below message and nothing happens

*"Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: ms-windows-store://pdp/?productid=9NJ46SX7X90P"*

I checked the python version by running python --version is git bash and it displays Python 2.7.2

Can someone please help me fix the issue with git commit ?

Comment: 'get staged and appear in green' you're clearly using some git frontend.  What program is it?  plain old `git bash` won't show anything if you type `git add xyz`, and AFAIK doesn't call python to do any commiting.  Also, you're on windows I assume?  That needs to be in the question too :)

Comment: I strongly suspect you have a `.git/hooks/pre-commit` hook which tries to fire a python script and targets a version of python which is not installed in your environment.

Comment: yes I am using git bash on windows 10. when I run git add <file_name>, the file is getting staged.
let me update the question. thanks for pointing out. let me know if something else is missing ? @2e0byo

Comment: could you add *exactly* what you typed into the shell? But I suspect @Zeitounator is right  What is in `.git/hooks` ?

Comment: this is the sequence of commands 
git status 
git add file1 file2 
git commit file1 -m "comment" >> get the mentioned warning here... 

@2e0byo
this is what is there in .git/hooks :

couple of folders : "bouncera" and "checks"

these files : commit-msg , post-checkout, post-commit, post-merge, pre-commit, pre-push 

one script : update_hooks.py

Comment: Clearly, your pre-commit hooks are not installed correctly. You can bypass them with `git commit -n`, but ideally you should find out from your team how your pre-commit hooks are supposed to be enabled.

Comment: @Zeitounator Is there a way to find out which version the hook is trying to invoke? I just tried with python 3.7 (earlier it was 2.7) by updating my PATH but still I get same warning. Is there a python dependency only with git commit ? because I don't get this warning with other commands like git add

Comment: @joanis sure, let me check

Comment: The pre commit hooks are scripts, you should be able to inspect them and see what they call. And you only see the problem with commit because other commands don't invoke the pre commit hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out if it is caused by a git hook using the following command:

```
strace git commit | grep access
```

If the reason for the error is a git hook, in the output, you'll be able to see that last accessed file like `.git/hooks/pre-commit`.

Comment: He asked about Windows, though